# My quick sort algorithm in Java doesn't work properly

Tags: java, quicksort

this is my quick sort code on Java. I've tried this code for 3 different types of lists;

- Random list
- Sorted List
- Reversed sorted list

It's working for only sorted list, but for sorted list it prints;

1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 66, 68, 64, 69, 62, 70, 60, 71, 58, 72, 56, 73, 54, 74, 52, 75, 50, 76, 48, 77, 46, 78, 44, 79, 42, 80, 40, 81, 38, 82, 36, 83, 34, 84, 32, 85, 30, 86, 28, 87, 26, 88, 24, 89, 22, 90, 20, 91, 18, 92, 16, 93, 14, 94, 12, 95, 10, 96, 8, 97, 6, 98, 4, 99, 2, 100

For the random list it changes.

I couldn't solve that problem, can anyone help? 
Thanks in advance.

```
class QuickSort {

  public int Partition(int[] numbers, int left, int right){
    int pivot = numbers[left];
    while (true)
    {
        while (numbers[left] < pivot)
            left++;

        while (numbers[right] > pivot)
            right--;

        if (left < right)
          {
            int temp = numbers[right];
            numbers[right] = numbers[left];
            numbers[left] = temp;
            left++;
            right--;
          }
          else
          {
                return right;
          }
    }
}

  public void QuickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    // For Recusrion
    if(left < right)
    {
        int pivot = Partition(arr, left, right);

        if(pivot > 1)
            QuickSort(arr, left, pivot - 1);

        if(pivot + 1 < right)
            QuickSort(arr, pivot + 1, right);
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public void printArray(int[] arr){
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
          if (i==arr.length-1)
              System.out.print(arr[i]);
          else
              System.out.print(arr[i]+", ");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }

  public int[] fillArraySorted(int len){
      int[] result=new int[len];
      int counter = 1;
      for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
          result[i]=counter; 
          counter++;
      }
      return result;
  }
  public int[] fillArrayRan(int len){
      int[] result=new int[len];
      Random r = new Random();
      for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
          result[i]=r.nextInt(100)+1; 
      }
      return result;
  }
  public int[] fillArraySortedReversed(int len){
      int[] result=new int[len];
      int counter = len;
      for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
          result[i]=counter; 
          counter--;
      }
      return result;
  }



}
}
```

Comment: [SO is not for code dumps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps). Please describe your problem, steps you've taken to try solving it, etc. Show input/output of shorter lists, too.

Comment: Your code is difficult to follow. Method names should begin with a lowercase character. Your local variable named pivot appears to relate to the left int, however your method returns the right int to a local variable also called pivot. Very confusing.